# .htaccess IIS mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

I have a problem importing a .htaccess file in my IIS mod_rewrite module.
3 errors appear.

> .htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On

##If your NeoFrag directory is not at http root
##you need to replace "/" by the correct directory, for example "RewriteBase /neofrag/"
RewriteBase /

##Allow direct access to specific directories
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(dir1|dir2)/
#RewriteRule .* - [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backups/

##Allow direct access to specific files
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /file1\.php [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /file2\.php [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|zip)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html
RewriteRule (.*)\.html(.*) $1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* index.php [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

> XML View

```
    <rewrite>
  <!--This directive was not converted because it is not supported by IIS: RewriteBase /.-->
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(dir1|dir2)/" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <!--This rule was not converted because only some of the conditions are using the OR flag.-->
    <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)\.html(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.html" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <!--The rule cannot be converted into an equivalent IIS format because of unsupported flags: E-->
```

Can some please help me on these 3 lines that are giving me an error?

- `RewriteBase /`
- `RewriteRule .* - [L,QSA]`
- `RewriteRule .* index.php [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteBase /
> ```

You could delete this line and include a slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. ie. Change the following lines:

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*)\.html(.*) $1$2 [R=301,L]
> RewriteRule .* index.php [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L,QSA]
> ```

to

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* /index.php [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L,QSA]
```

> This rule was not converted because only some of the conditions are using the OR flag

The converter appears to be trying to convert the commented out code?? Delete all lines that start `#`.

> ```
> RewriteRule .* /index.php [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L,QSA]
> ```

The `E` flag sets an environment variable. I don't speak IIS, but you could remove the `E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},` part in the above directive and instead use mod_setenvif (will this convert?). For example, that `E` flag is equivalent to the following:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" REMOTE_USER=$1
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted to remove it from the unanswered question queue (checkmark on the left). Once you have 15+ rep you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: The website works page wise, but now we can"t login on the website and create database entries from the website.

Comment: Maybe the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable isn't being set? Did this bit of code seemingly convert OK? What do you see in your (Web.)config file?